# SQL Select everything besides the most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table where I would like to pull all the dates in it besides the most recent one. I tried the following but it's giving me an error " an aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list"

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
groupId, 
Types,
MAX(Dates) as date

FROM TableData

Where Dates < Max(dates)

GROUP BY 
groupId, 
Types

//The table looks as follows:
ID      |   GroupID | Date
1       |     A     | 10-10-2020 -> don't show
2       |     A     | 09-10-2020
3       |     A     | 08-10-2020
4       |     B     | 10-10-2020 -> don't show
5       |     B     | 09-10-2020
6       |     B     | 08-10-2020


//Expected result:
GroupID | Date
  A     | 09-10-2020
  A     | 08-10-2020
  B     | 09-10-2020
  B     | 08-10-2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the rows in the table expect for the one(s) whose date matches the latest date in the table, one option uses a subquery:

```
select t.*
from tabledata t
where date < (select max(date) from tabledata)
```

You can also express this with window functions (but it will not necessarily perform better):

```
select *
from (select t.*, max(date) over() max_date from tabledata t) t
where date < max_date
```

---

**Edit**: if you want that logic on a per-`id` basis, then we need to *correlate* the subquery:

```
select t.*
from tabledata t
where date < (select max(t1.date) from tabledata t1 where t1.id = t.id)
```

... or to use a `partition by` clause in the window `max()`:

```
select *
from (select t.*, max(date) over(partition by id) max_date from tabledata t) t
where date < max_date
```

Comment: Hi GMB
The only thing that confuses me about the subquery is that if the subquery dates  get the whole table data or just the matching id?

Comment: @MishMish: that's the max date in the whole table. But it can easily be tweaked to accmondate the other scenario, if that's what you want (although it is not what you seem to have asked).

Comment: Yea that's i wanted, that why I grouped by the ID. But i know my question is badly explained

Comment: Thanks dude, once i test it ill get back to you

Comment: I just edit my question with an input and expected result, hopefully it makes more sense now

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DENSE_RANK` as well

```
select max_cte as (
    select *, dense_rank() over (parition by id order by [dates] desc) max_rnk
    from TableData)
select Id, [Types], MAX(Dates) as [date]
from max_cte 
where max_rnk>1
group by Id, [Types];
```